# Dimensional Regularization of the Higgs Mass Correction

Tags: resource-recommendations, standard-model, renormalization, higgs, dimensional-regularization

I've found plenty of blog posts and papers where the authors claim that the Higgs mass divergence (usually presented with a momentum cutoff) doesn't show up under dimensional regularization. Unfortunately I've never seen a book or paper which explains this with any more detail: it's usually just stated as a fact. Is there some specific reference that people can point to for this?

I'm well aware that dimensional regularization just hides the hierarchy problem until physical particles are added, but I want to include a reference to motivate the introduction of new particles without going to through dimensional regularization.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105764/  maybe give you a clue.